# icons loads twice in akzhan jwysiwyg

Tags: ajax, editor, wysiwyg

[image: problem with akzhan wysiwyg]

My page get loaded from ajax (jquery). Editor works well but load control twice.

When the page loads without ajax, it works perfect. But when the editor load in ajax loaded page, it loads control twice.

My code is as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/admin/js/wysiwyg/jquery.wysiwyg.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/admin/js/wysiwyg/jquery.wysiwyg.css" type="text/css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //$('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg();
        $('.wysiwyg').wysiwyg({
        controls: {
            strikeThrough: { visible: false },
            insertTable: { visible: false },
            superscript: { visible: false }
        }
    });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
<textarea class="wysiwyg" name="description" cols="50" rows="4" ></textarea>
```

Comment: amazing .. it looks fine in IE..
only problem in firefox..

Comment: would help if you could setup an example somewhere.